# Linking objects produces weird results

Tags: objects, particles

I'm doing a blender course in which I'm modeling a patch of grass. I had to make several patches using a Particle System and applying a Particle system and making several variations on the same patch using all the different settings for scaling, rotation etc.

Now I want to link all the individual strands in a patch together. I click one strand, then use <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select them all, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> . And then Boom! This mumbo-jumbo appears.

I follow every step of the tutorial exactly as described, and also other tutorials on youtube on this subject. I have not been able to find anything about this particular error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do all this as **Random** option is available in the particle system settings in regard to the particles' scale and rotation. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! It the hotkey <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> is for joining the meshes together. It sounds correct in the context but what it does in the background is it joins them together applying all the properties of the later selected mesh which includes the particle System, which is what provides you with the "mumbo-jumbo". What you would want is to group the items together using the hotkey <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to create a group of the patches you want whilst making sure not to mess up the particle system of individual meshes.

Comment: Hope the answer helps. let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: Thank you! I now worked it out, I used a wrong setting when making the objects as a single from the object - relations menu!